# Auto resize the UIView based on UILabel's content through Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I have a requirement on showing a banner view to show a message,

Now the message's content may vary and the view should also resize depending on `UILabel`s content.

`UILabel` is set to `Word Wrap` and `numberOfLines` is set to `0`

The design in `xib` is,
[image: Auto layout][image: Auto Layout 2]

And the respective class file is,

```
import UIKit

class ORABannerView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerText: UILabel!

    static func instantiate(message: String) -> ORABannerView {
        let view: ORABannerView = initFromNib() ?? ORABannerView()
        view.bannerText.text = message
        return view
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
    }
}
```

The `initFromNib` is an implemented as UIView's extension,

```
extension UIView {
    class func initFromNib<T: UIView>() -> T? {
        guard let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: self), owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as? T else {
            return nil
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Tried with `layoutIfNeeded()` on the view, but it's not working for me.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try the following code,

Create a method `sizeHeaderToFit` and which returns height of the `UIView` based on its content's height.

```
private func sizeHeaderToFit(headerView: UIView?) -> CGFloat {
       guard let headerView = headerView else {
           return 0.0
       }

       headerView.setNeedsLayout()
       headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

       let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height

       return height
   }
```

Then you can call the above method from the respective code,

```
sizeHeaderToFit(headerView: yourView)
```

In `ORABannerView` class, add override `layoutSubviews`,

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
       bannerText.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = bannerText.bounds.width
   }
```

And in `xib` file, keep the constraints to its `superview` rather than `safe area` for code optimisation. [Optional]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Let me try with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove trailing OR leading constraints
2. set the size to fit property programmatically

Comment: I am looking for a solution in xib file itself, mainly with constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the class to look like

```
class ORABannerView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerText: UILabel!

    static func instantiate(message: String) -> ORABannerView {
        let view: ORABannerView = initFromNib()
        view.bannerText.text = message
        return view
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
    }
}
```

---

```
let v = ORABannerView.instantiate(message: "djhhejjhsdjhdjhjhdshdsjhdshjdhjdhjdhjddhjhjdshjdhdjshjshjdshjdshjdshjdshjdsjhdshjds")

self.view.addSubview(v)

v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

    v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor,constant:50),

    v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor,constant:0),

    v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor,constant:0)

])
```

[image]

Comment: I added my `initWithNib` method

Comment: No need to set bottom anchor?

Comment: do you want to show the banner from top or bottom ? if top set top  constraint and if  bottom set the bottom , regrading the label you need to set  leading ,trailing ,top and bottom

Comment: set it in xib no problem

Comment: is it not possible to do it in xib file itself instead of setting anchors in code?

Comment: @Bappaditya the anchors are used to specify position and width of the view , which are required to wrap the view , do you think that this even possible from the xib ? it's like setting frame without the height to make extend according to label content

Comment: Yes @Sh_Khan, I was looking for the solution on xib instead of code? or is there any better solution?

Comment: the xib can't know where to be placed in terms of position

Answer (score 0):

New users autolayout, always forgot about two useful constraints:

```
func setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority, for: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis)
func setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority, for: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis)
```

It also exists in IB too: 
[image]

Try to play with the priority parameter

Comment: let me give it a try, btw did you try the same thing and it worked for you?